# Pyspark dataframe counting and printing null rows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

There is some behaviour I don't quite understand of the `Pyspark DataFrame`.

Have have the following code:

```
#Assert that the sale date is not null for any record
df_sale_date_null_count = df.filter(df.sale_date.isNull()).count()

if df_sale_date_null_count > 0:
    logger.info(f"Sale date is null for {df_sale_date_null_count} records. Here are the first 10:")
    logger.info(f"First 10: {str(df.filter(df.sale_date.isNull()).limit(10).collect())}")
```

**Result of running this code:**

Now, inspecting the logs it prints:

Line 1: "Sale date is null for 400 records. Here are the first 10:

Line 2: First 10: []

My question: Why is line 2 printing an empty dataframe when clearly there are 400 rows satisfying the null condition? I think I might be missing something about how these things are evaluated

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to store the **result into string** then use it in your `logger.info`

**`Example:`**

```
#Assert that the sale date is not null for any record

df_sale_date_null_count = df.filter(df.sale_date.isNull()).count()

if df_sale_date_null_count > 0:
    logger.info(f"Sale date is null for {df_sale_date_null_count} records. Here are the first 10:")
    clt_str =  str(df.filter(df.sale_date.isNull()).limit(10).collect())
    logger.info(f"First 10: {clt_str}")
```

Comment: Turned out to fix it.. I'm not sure why though?